# Tensorflow: x - reduce_mean(x) has gradient 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, derivative

I was observing gradients when I noticed that the gradient of subtracting one's axis' mean is zero. I think this is very counter-intuitive because gradient = 0 normally means the function is constant. Can anyone explain intuitively why the gradient here is zero?

```
import tensorflow as tf

o1 = tf.random.normal((3, 3, 3, 3))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(o1)
    o2 = o1-tf.reduce_mean(o1, 1, keepdims=True)

d = tape.gradient(o2, o1)
tf.print(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(d)))
```

outputs me 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `tape.gradient`, when passed a tensor, will first compute the *sum* of the tensor and then compute the gradient of the resulting scalar. That is, `tape.gradient` *only* computes gradients of scalar functions.

Now, since you subtract the mean off of `o1`, the mean (and thus the sum) of the output will always be 0. It doesn't matter how `o1` is changed, you are always subtracting the mean, and so the output will never change from 0, and thus you get a gradient of 0.

Note: `GradientTape` has a [`jacobian` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) which computes a full Jacobian matrix and does not require scalar outputs.

Comment: Thanks. For learning, the optimizer uses the Jacobian and not the zero gradient, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that the concept of gradient, is only for scalar functions, not for vector ones.

Comment: @Philipp123 that depends on the code. The standard `model.fit` in Keras, for example, will use `tape.gradient` followed by the optimizer applying those gradients. If you want to train using jacobians, you will need to write some custom code.

Comment: But since the loss is scalar, using the gradient is meaningful but not for some multidimensional output. Thanks, I guess I got it